# Consuming REST services in Angular 6 using HttpClient gives Observable value as undefined when subscribed

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-httpclient, angular-observable

I have created an Angular service which returns an **Observable** array of objects, using `of` from `rxjs`:

```
export class HackfestService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getHackfests():Observable<HackFestDetails[]>{
    return of([
      {hackfestId: 1, hackfestName: "Hackfest Alpha",hackfestDate: new Date('June 12, 2018'), noOfParticipants: 500, noClearedPre: 100, isFinalResultOut:true, isPreResultOut:true},
      {hackfestId: 2, hackfestName: "Hackfest Beta",hackfestDate: new Date('July 22, 2018'), noOfParticipants: 0, noClearedPre:0 , isFinalResultOut:false, isPreResultOut:false}
    ]);
  }
}
```

It works fine until i replace the `of` part with an actual `HttpClient.get()` request like this:

```
export class HackfestService {

  private hackfestsURL =  'http://localhost:57161/api/Hackfest/GetHackfests';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getHackfests():Observable<HackFestDetails[]>{
    // return of([
    //   {hackfestId: 1, hackfestName: "Hackfest Alpha",hackfestDate: new Date('June 12, 2018'), noOfParticipants: 500, noClearedPre: 100, isFinalResultOut:true, isPreResultOut:true},
    //   {hackfestId: 2, hackfestName: "Hackfest Beta",hackfestDate: new Date('July 22, 2018'), noOfParticipants: 0, noClearedPre:0 , isFinalResultOut:false, isPreResultOut:false}
    // ]);
    return this.http.get<HackFestDetails[]>(this.hackfestsURL);
  }
}
```

I have tested the URL which gives the JSON result as:

```
    [{"hackfestId":1,"hackfestName":"Hackfest Alpha","hackfestDate":"2018-06-12T00:00:00","noOfParticipants":100,"noClearedPre":100,"isFinalResultOut":true,"isPreResultOut":true},
    {"hackfestId":2,"hackfestName":"Hackfest Beta","hackfestDate":"2018-07-22T00:00:00","noOfParticipants":0,"noClearedPre":0,"isFinalResultOut":false,"isPreResultOut":false}]
```

I have subscribed to the observable in my component as:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.getHackfestList();
    this.selectedHackfest = this.allHackfests[0];
  }

  getHackfestList():void{
    //call api and get the list sorted in descending order of festival date
    this.hackfestService.getHackfests().subscribe(items => {
      this.allHackfests = items;
      console.log(this.allHackfests);
    });

    this.allHackfests.sort((x:HackFestDetails, y:HackFestDetails)=>{return y.hackfestDate.getTime()-x.hackfestDate.getTime()} );
  }
```

A  `console.log()` inside the subscribe method **actually logs the received JSON data** from  the `HttpClient.get()` method, but the attribute `this.allHackfests` remains `undefined` and hence gives errors when i try to access any of its attributes.

The official [tutorial for Angular 6](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) had a similar implementation for which they state:

> You've swapped of for http.get and the app keeps working without any
>   other changes because both functions return an Observable

Clearly the statement is not consistent with what i observe in my implementation. Is there some more change that i might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `getHackfests()` is an asynchronous function.

The code will not wait and will execute the next lines, hence the error.

You should move the `sort` part inside the `subscribe`.

Comment: But how does it work in case of call using Of ? It is also returning an observable. Also, it works fine in the official angular 6 tutorial.